# AntD Icon should have type prop or component prop error using in Tab component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm getting this error on my app

`` Warning: [antd: Icon] Should have `type` prop or `component` prop or `children`. ``

I'm using Icons inside my Tab component
Here's my code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-browser-m3mwx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from "icon: """

```
const tabPanes = [
    {
      key: "1",
      title: "All",
      icon: "",
      content: (
        <DataTable
          dataSource={isAll}
          columns={columns}
          loading={state.loading}
          pagination={state.pagination}
          onChange={handleTableChange}
        />
      ),
      count: 12
    },
```

Comment: Ooohh I don't need an Icon in All tab. What will be the work around? 
Updates: Thank you! I already fix it by having conditional code